# Memory Leak in Windows Phone 8 Application

Tags: c#, windows-phone, msdn

I am trying to create a listbox containing an Image and some details of it.
Here is the code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="GalleryImages" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" Orientation="Vertical" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageSrc}" Height="200" Width="480" Stretch="Fill"/>
                    <Border BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="10" >
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="White" Opacity="0.6">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Time}" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="10,5,10,0" FontSize="12" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Day}" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  FontSize="45" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="10,0,10,10" Margin="0,-10,0,-18"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MonthAndYear}" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="17" Padding="10,0,10,5"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

the backened code is:

```
public class Item
    {
        public ImageSource ImageSrc { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }
        public string Day { get; set; }
        public string MonthAndYear { get; set; }
    }

//Creating a New Item
//Added the time,day, monthandyear
//Now adding the image source
//This will be looped each time for each image

Item item = new Item();
using (IsolatedStorageFile ISF = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
     if (ISF.DirectoryExists("SomeDirectory"))
     using (IsolatedStorageFileStream FS = ISF.OpenFile("SomeDirectory/" + "SOMERANDOMIMAGENAME", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
     {
            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.SetSource(FS);
            item.ImageSrc = bitmap;
      }
 }
```

At last binding the items to the listbox one-by-one created before:

```
 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => GalleryImages.Items.Add(item));
```

**Now the problem is:**
As you can see that all the listbox images are being fetched from the Isolated Storage using a new Bitmap Image and then setting it to the item.ImageSrc. But when the items go beyond 25 it creates a Memory Leak and the app crashes after **displaying** the images

what i tried till now,

1. added virtualizingstackpanel, which worked but, not for images beyond 25.
2. set the item.ImageSrc = null just after adding the item to the GalleryImage(ListBox) Items, but that makes the images of the ListBox null too.

What else i can do to work this out, for images more than 1000??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with collection that contains image, not only UI controls to display the collection that takes considerable amount of memory, but the collection it self too. So, try to look into [Data Virtualization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22186752/2998271) in addition to [UI Virtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

With data virtualization, not all items in the collection loaded to memory at a time. Only portion of it loaded, those needed to be displayed currently plus several next items as *buffer*.

Comment: Data Virtualization and UI Virtualization are same concept ?
Does both of them or anyone of them support to winodws phone 8 ?