# Can I bind a database with million records to a listbox?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, binding, windows-phone

Can I bind a list with over 1,000,000 records to a list box so that the list box is dynamically populated from the sqlite database as the user scrolls.

This is needed to show all our data in a list box without throwing an outofmemory exception. Is there any built in methods or framework's that I can use or do I need to build the control myself?

Also are there any disadvantages of this.

Cheers

Comment: I don't want to, iv been told to...

Comment: Well is there anyway to directly bind data from a sqlite database?

Comment: If that's an option, have a look at Telerik's RadDataBoundListBox. It is pretty good for lazy loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should virtualize UI and data loading. You can't just bind 1,000,000 item collection to the list without any code. Read this tutorial about [displaying large data sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Well i can't add 1,000,000 items to a list or it will throw an out of memory exception, so if there a way to only request it when I need it. Or do I need to create these controls my self.

Comment: Read [the answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186076/how-to-do-data-virtualization-for-online-content-in-windows-phone), you should virtualize the collection. There some basic code provided.